# How to Connect to IntraNet Web Service using the Windows Mobile Device emulator?

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, smartphone

I have my Windows Mobile Application which connect to the Intranet Web Service. I am not able to access the internet/intranet resource using the emulator.. What i have tried is

1. Installed Windows Mobile Center
2. Opened the Emulator
3. Given Cradle
4. Ran the application
5. Application Fails due to unavailability of the Web Service

Please help me???

Comment: Is the rest of the application working fine? Only the web service connectivity is giving an error?

Comment: Yes, Rest of the application is working fine.. Connecting to WEB SErvice is the problem...

Comment: If invoked independently, is the web service running properly?

Comment: Yes, I have checked using my Browser, It is working very fine....